# Third party solar monitoring system

Tags: modbus

Dear Raspberry Pi community,

I’m a total newbie when it comes to Raspberry Pi and such devices. I have a task at my university to perform an analysis of the use of artificial intelligence to manage and forecast electricity production in "zero export" photovoltaic systems. I need to create a third party solar monitoring system to control of the value of generated power, taking into account: energy consumption, generation value, short-term consumption forecast, storage capacity.

All I’ve been told that I should use the Raspberry Pi and Modbus TCP/IP protocol to communicate with solar inverters. Sadly I don’t have a physical access to solar inverters to control them. I’ve been wondering if it’s possible to read PV data like generation value, energy consumption, insolation etc. from Matlab Simulink inverter model and then somehow use Raspberry Pi to control those virtual inverters? Sorry if what I’m saying makes no sense, but I really don’t know where to start. I’ve browsed a ton of internet pages, but I couldn’t find such implementation and I honestly have no clue how to solve my problem. I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: what does your question have to do with the Raspberry Pi? ... it is a question about a link between Matlab Simulink and hardware device ... until you discover how to establish the link, the RPi is irrelevant

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so much a Pi question as a software design question. My remarks are a bit long for comments, therefore as answer.

A simple way to do this is to de-couple the reading of the data (either from an filetransfer from you matlab system  or the modbus connection) from the actual calculations. In that way, you can create you AI forecast system independently from your data gathering: it takes the input file(s) to do the forcast.

For the generation of the files, you can create files with matlab. And when you get access to a solar system, you cab create a separate program that generates the same files (same layout, same record definition) from the modbus. But if you don't have/get access to solar systems, you will never be able to prove that that works.

Think careful about the data that is in the files. A good definition of these datafiles will save a lot of effort lateron.